# The method is never used locally

Tags: android, android-webview, proguard

It says "the method openFileChooser(...) is never used locally", and when I obfuscate, proguard removes them, so it doesn't work. Without obfuscation it works without any problem. How can I avoid proguard removing them?
Here is the code:

```
mWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            i.setType("image/*");  
            Main.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  
           }

        // for android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               Main.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), Main.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );
           }
    });
```

I can't use @Override, and I think its their mistake, that I can't override. @KeepName also doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`openFileChooser` is not a public Android API and has never been part of the SDK (that's why you can't @Override it). It's an internal API that just happens to work on many Android versions (but not KitKat+) and Android devices but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell ProGuard to preserve the method with

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
    public void openFileChooser(android.webkit.ValueCallback, java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
}
```